# Confused with integral and natural logarithm

Tags: integration, logarithms

When reading about ideal gas and adiabatic expansion, I got stuck with the following:
    $$W_{ab}=\int_{{\it V_a}}^{{\it V_b}}\!\,{\rm }\frac{dV}{V^\alpha}=\frac{V_b^{1-\alpha}-V_a^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}$$

I know the following rule, but I couldn't come to the above: 
$$\int_{{\it V_a}}^{{\it V_b}}\!\,{\rm }\frac{dV}{V}=ln|\frac{V_b}{V_a}|$$

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as $$\int_{V_a}^{V_b} V^{-\alpha} \ dV$$ It is obvious, that a 1 has to be added to the exponent to get the integral. If you differentiate a polynomial, the exponent decreases by 1.

$$\int_{V_a}^{V_b} V^{-\alpha} \ dV= b\cdot V^{1-\alpha}\bigg|_{V_a}^{V_b}$$

b is a unknown factor.

If you differentiate $b\cdot V^{1-\alpha}$ you get $b\cdot (1-\alpha ) V^{-\alpha}$.

Thus the factor b has to be $\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$.

Comment: @GertjanDeMulder Your are welcome.

Comment: does your technique has a specific name in Mathematics? So I could do some "research" about it, to upgrade my math skills.

Comment: @GertjanDeMulder Something like "Integration of Polynomials"